# Setup HREF for Mailto:

Tags: javascript, html, html-email

Error Message: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

I noticed the problem is `href="mailto:<a id="Email">...` is with in the `""`, but how can I change the Email ID without moving the mailto to javascript? or is it possable.

I know with Javascript there is link coding but is there same in HTML? (example: `href='mailto:'<a id="Email">'...`

```js
function Email_Address() {

  var emailaddress = document.getElementByID("EmailAddress").value;
  document.getElementById("Email").innerHTML = emailaddress;

}
```

```html
Email Address: <input type="text" id="EmailAddress" onkeyup="Email_Address()" onchange="Email_Address()">
<br>
<br>
<a href='mailto:<a id="Email">?subject=Test&body=This%20is%20Test'><button>Email</button></a>
```

Comment: why is there an anchor tag inside the href?

Comment: Your anchor tag is not valid

Comment: The right syntax is `<a href="mailto:user.name@example.com">user.name@example.com</a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the whole `href` tag in javascript. You cannot do this with HTML. Try the following:

```
Email Address: <input type="text" id="EmailAddress" onkeyup="Email_Address()" onchange="Email_Address()">
<br>
<br>
<a id="anchorMail"><button>Email</button></a>
```

And in JS:

```
function Email_Address() {
    var emailaddress = document.getElementByID("EmailAddress").value;
    document.getElementById("anchorMail").href = 'mailto:'+ emailaddress +'?subject=Test&body=This%20is%20Test';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put elements inside attribute values.

Put the ID on the anchor start tag you have already.

Use string replacement to change the email address.

```
 <a id="Email" href='mailto:PLACEHOLDER?subject=Test&body=This%20is%20Test'>

document.getElementById("Email").href = 
     document.getElementById("Email").href.replace("PLACEHOLDER", emailaddress);
```

Note: You cannot have a `<button>` inside the `<a>`. Since you are linking to a URL, use an `<a>`. Use CSS if you want it to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='mailto:<a id="Email">?subject=Test&body=This%20is%20Test'><button>Email</button></a>
```

*That line of code above* is **invalid HTML**, because of the [anchor tag specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks) which you can take your time to read, also feel free to jump into the `mailTo` section.

So in order to make your code valid:

```
<a href='mailto:someemailaddress@somewhere.org&subject=Test&body=This%20is%20Test' id="email">Email</a>
```

Note how I removed the `<button>` tag from within your `<a>` tag. That is because it is unnecessary, you can use CSS to modify the above anchor tag by id `#email` to make it look and feel like a button. There is plenty of very helpful online references can help you achieve that here.

Now, in JavaScript you can modify the above anchor element by accessing it using it's `id` like so:

```
function Email_Address() {
  // grabbing the value of an element with ID of `EmailAddress`
  var emailAddress = document.getElementByID("EmailAddress").value;
  // setting the value of `emailaddress` to the element with ID of `email`.
  document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = emailAddress;
}
```